# What kind of bike is this, found in basement

Tags: identify-this-bike

i got these pictures from my dad, can someone tell from what era this bike is? And is this something valuable/rare?
The owner died last year, he was 86. Lived in flanders, belgium.

​​​​​​​Any help would be more than welcome

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Probably dates from around 1970.  Bocama/BCM is apparently the frame manufacturer.  Probably not especially valuable.

Comment: I'm sure it was valuable to the person who rode it.  Looks like a nice bike, and could be a perfectly good daily rider after a cleanup and replace of the wear components.

Comment: It may be the picture (#1) but I'd check that fork. It had a front impact, probably!

Answer (score 4):

Starting with the last picture first...

According to Google translate "velos" is French for Bicycle. "Sport" is probably a model.
The picture also shows Mafac Racer center pull brakes - Mafac is a French company

On the middle picture - Bocama BCM is a type of lug used to build frames. [Here's a catalog](http://2velo.com/bocama-lugs-bcm-catalog/). The catalog is in French.

The first picture is so dark it's hard to tell much about the bike. From what little I can see it looks to be equipped like a 1970s era low end Peugeot.
Without more clues this is as much as I can find.

Value - it's worth what someone is willing to pay for it. The only way to judge value is to sell the bike and see what people are ready to pay.
As a bike geek I love seeing these bikes and the history they represent but that does not translate into actual dollars.

Comment: Confirming that Bocama made parts, not bikes.  They were known for lugs and fork crowns, so they were to frames what a groupset is to a whole bike  - a component.

Comment: Thanks guys, ill try to get him in my hands, and will take some more decent picture if you guys would be interested